# Firebase event parameters not available in Google Analytics 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have a game and I am trying to monitor users' drop-rates at certain points.
The event seems to trigger correctly returning the right parameters (in firebase). The issue is that the parameter in Firebase is not available in GA4 (in funnel exploration for example, cannot find it in the parameters list).

Does anyone have any clue?

In picture 1 - I'm trying to exemplify the event available in Firebase
In picture 2 - not sure I am doing what I am supposed to but was trying to configure a custom metric based on the parameter of the event Mission_Finish

[Firebase_Event_Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5qa4.jpg) [Custom_Metrics_GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74IFY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you have events in firebase and connection to GA4 then follow this steps to add event in funnel exploration.

1. Open funnel
2. Go under **Tab Setting** -> **STEPS** and press edit (the image in the upper right corner of STEPS box)
3. Under Step 1 I currently have first_open. I can change that with my custom events from firebase in dropdown. Look at the image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
The issue I was having is that the parameters of the events in Firebase were not available in GA4. It seems that defining a custom dimension fixed the situation, but with a delay (took some time to properly associate with the correct parameter in Firebase)

Comment: Great. You can write that as an answer, and maybe add some instructions or images how to set custom dimension, so that other users with same problem can follow your steps.